# How to detect if QT main class is already present in memory

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency

During the last ten years, we have programmed different functional extensions (as DLLs) using the API of a CAD program, all use QT. All serve other purposes and are individual projects in various IDEs (QTCreator / VS2010 / VS2015).

Apparently, for the first time now, a customer needs to run two or three of these extension DLLs concurrently.
We have no control over which DLL gets loaded (the individual user determines this) or in which order these are loaded (the CAD application determines this).

With the secondly loaded DLL, we get runtime errors as the QT main object can only exist once. Strange things happen.

**Question:** How can a DLL at its start inquire about the presence of the global QT object (without having a reference to it) and then either create a new one or attach to the existing one?

Sorry, but we could not find a solution in the QT doc or by asking Ma Google; the QT support was of no help, too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check the value returned by `QCoreApplication::instance()` before you create a new one?